# Failing to compile golang project in gitlab-ci using docker image

Tags: docker, go, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm failing to build my golang project using gitlab-ci.
When running dep init inside of project directory it fetches only part of my dependencies, and when tries to build binary fails with error that dependencies aren't found. When I'm building my project on osx, or running docker golang image to compile project on osx it builds successfully.

My .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: golang:1.9.2

variables:
  REPO_NAME: storage

before_script:
  - mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/$REPO_NAME
  - ln -svf $CI_PROJECT_DIR/* $GOPATH/src/$REPO_NAME
  - cd $GOPATH/src/$REPO_NAME
  - go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
  - dep init

stages:
  - compile

compile:
    stage: compile
    script:
      - go build -o $CI_PROJECT_DIR/main
    artifacts:
      paths:
        - main
```

Output of gitlab-runner task:

```
[0KRunning with gitlab-runner 10.2.0 (0a75cdd1)
  on docker-auto-scale (4e4528ca)
[0;m[0KUsing Docker executor with image golang:1.9.2 ...
[0;m[0KUsing docker image sha256:5f8b4886692c4897e1f0855043da1896fe4f1e6762fccddfa2114a2fdfa1674f for predefined container...
[0;m[0KPulling docker image golang:1.9.2 ...
[0;m[0KUsing docker image golang:1.9.2 ID=sha256:1a34fad76b34f485ebc72d32044cafe963ae00c8e80dbf4115bafabd31e93ff6 for build container...
[0;msection_start:1511994825:prepare_script
[0KRunning on runner-4e4528ca-project-4778312-concurrent-0 via runner-4e4528ca-srm-1511994698-320032ac...
section_end:1511994828:prepare_script
[0Ksection_start:1511994828:get_sources
[0K[32;1mCloning repository...[0;m
Cloning into '/builds/group-name/service-storage'...
[32;1mChecking out f59f57e4 as master...[0;m
[32;1mSkipping Git submodules setup[0;m
section_end:1511994831:get_sources
[0Ksection_start:1511994831:restore_cache
[0Ksection_end:1511994832:restore_cache
[0Ksection_start:1511994832:download_artifacts
[0Ksection_end:1511994834:download_artifacts
[0Ksection_start:1511994834:build_script
[0K[32;1m$ mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/$REPO_NAME[0;m
[32;1m$ ln -svf $CI_PROJECT_DIR/* $GOPATH/src/$REPO_NAME[0;m
'/go/src/storage/Dockerfile' -> '/builds/group-name/service-storage/Dockerfile'
'/go/src/storage/aws' -> '/builds/group-name/service-storage/aws'
'/go/src/storage/db' -> '/builds/group-name/service-storage/db'
'/go/src/storage/logHelper' -> '/builds/group-name/service-storage/logHelper'
'/go/src/storage/main' -> '/builds/group-name/service-storage/main'
'/go/src/storage/main.go' -> '/builds/group-name/service-storage/main.go'
'/go/src/storage/responses' -> '/builds/group-name/service-storage/responses'
'/go/src/storage/routers' -> '/builds/group-name/service-storage/routers'
[32;1m$ cd $GOPATH/src/$REPO_NAME[0;m
[32;1m$ go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep[0;m
[32;1m$ dep init[0;m
  Using ^1.2.0 as constraint for direct dep github.com/joho/godotenv
  Locking in v1.2.0 (a79fa1e) for direct dep github.com/joho/godotenv
  Using ^1.6.0 as constraint for direct dep github.com/gorilla/mux
  Locking in v1.6.0 (7f08801) for direct dep github.com/gorilla/mux
  Locking in v1.1 (1ea2538) for transitive dep github.com/gorilla/context
[32;1m$ go build -o $CI_PROJECT_DIR/main[0;m
aws/aws.go:16:2: cannot find package "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws" in any of:
    /go/src/storage/vendor/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws (vendor tree)
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws (from $GOPATH)
aws/aws.go:17:2: cannot find package "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials" in any of:
    /go/src/storage/vendor/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials (vendor tree)
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials (from $GOPATH)
aws/aws.go:18:2: cannot find package "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session" in any of:
    /go/src/storage/vendor/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session (vendor tree)
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session (from $GOPATH)
aws/aws.go:19:2: cannot find package "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3" in any of:
    /go/src/storage/vendor/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3 (vendor tree)
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3 (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3 (from $GOPATH)
routers/v1/images/imageFunctions/save_images.go:23:2: cannot find package "github.com/disintegration/imaging" in any of:
    /go/src/storage/vendor/github.com/disintegration/imaging (vendor tree)
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/disintegration/imaging (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/github.com/disintegration/imaging (from $GOPATH)
db/dbFunctions/db_functions.go:7:2: cannot find package "github.com/satori/go.uuid" in any of:
    /go/src/storage/vendor/github.com/satori/go.uuid (vendor tree)
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/satori/go.uuid (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/github.com/satori/go.uuid (from $GOPATH)
db/db.go:13:2: cannot find package "gopkg.in/mgo.v2" in any of:
    /go/src/storage/vendor/gopkg.in/mgo.v2 (vendor tree)
    /usr/local/go/src/gopkg.in/mgo.v2 (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/gopkg.in/mgo.v2 (from $GOPATH)
db/db.go:14:2: cannot find package "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson" in any of:
    /go/src/storage/vendor/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson (vendor tree)
    /usr/local/go/src/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson (from $GOPATH)
section_end:1511994846:build_script
[0Ksection_start:1511994846:after_script
[0Ksection_end:1511994847:after_script
[0K[31;1mERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
[0;m
```

When running locally on osx, I see that dep init pulls all dependencies, and after that I can successfully run go build and it will build binary.

```
username@hostname storage (master) $ dep init
  Locking in v1.1 (1ea2538) for transitive dep github.com/gorilla/context
  Locking in v1.32.0 (32e4c1e) for transitive dep github.com/go-ini/ini
  Locking in master (f7e31b4) for transitive dep golang.org/x/image
  Using ^1.6.0 as constraint for direct dep github.com/gorilla/mux
  Locking in v1.6.0 (7f08801) for direct dep github.com/gorilla/mux
  Using ^1.1.0 as constraint for direct dep github.com/satori/go.uuid
  Locking in v1.1.0 (879c588) for direct dep github.com/satori/go.uuid
  Using ^1.2.0 as constraint for direct dep github.com/joho/godotenv
  Locking in v1.2.0 (a79fa1e) for direct dep github.com/joho/godotenv
  Using ^1.12.36 as constraint for direct dep github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go
  Locking in v1.12.36 (5bcc0a2) for direct dep github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go
  Locking in  (0b12d6b5) for transitive dep github.com/jmespath/go-jmespath
  Using v2 as constraint for direct dep gopkg.in/mgo.v2
  Locking in v2 (3f83fa5) for direct dep gopkg.in/mgo.v2
  Using ^1.2.4 as constraint for direct dep github.com/disintegration/imaging
  Locking in v1.2.4 (dd50a3e) for direct dep github.com/disintegration/imaging
```

Also I have tried to run on OSX locally using docker golang image and it compiles fine:

```
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/go/src/storage -w /go/src/storage golang:1.9.2 go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep && dep init

docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/go/src/storage -w /go/src/storage golang:1.9.2 go build -v -o main
```

Problem only exists, running on gitlab-ci.

Tried various golang images, alpine and others. Same result, it always fails with same missing dependencies.

**Update and Solution example:**

As user @vardius pointed and comments and later made an answer, problem was with symlinking.

Replaced my line in .gitlab-ci.yml from:

```
- ln -svf $CI_PROJECT_DIR/* $GOPATH/src/$REPO_NAME
```

to

```
- cp -rf $CI_PROJECT_DIR/* $GOPATH/src/$REPO_NAME/
```

and everything compiled.

Comment: I'm not sure how gitlab-ci works, but would it fix your problem if you vendor your dependencies, deploy them together with your project, and just not run dep at all?

Comment: Dependencies (vendor) are compiled to *.so files, they should be compiled in same environment where binary is compiled. Also deps are 150 megabytes. Would be to heavy to store and update them every time. Gitlab-CI runner should do all compiling, building, testing and deploying process. I've posted only compile section which is failing. Developer needs only to write code and push it to gitlab. Everything should be done by Gitlab-CI runner.

Comment: @mkopriva Please see my upper comment. Maybe I'm missing something ? I'm a novice at Golang

Comment: Usually, and your case may differ, Go dependencies are kept in a vendor folder inside the project folder, and they are kept in their original form, *.go. That means that if you have all your Go deps in the vendor folder inside your project, push that to a remote server, and run go install, your project should be compiled together with the deps and without an issue.

Comment: @mkopriva Do I need to also push Gopkg.lock and Gopkg.toml files to my repository in case if I'm pushing vendor directory? I will use your suggestion as a backup variant, if no one will offer how to solve problem with Gitlab-CI

Comment: @mkopriva I took, one of my dependencies, and did inspection of their repository. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go They have pushed their vendor and also Gopkg.toml and Gopkg.lock files to their repository. Is it normal practice with golang to push vendor and those files ?

Comment: On the requirement of having the lock files in vendor when deploying: I don't really think so, the vendor directory itself is recognized by default by Go since version 1.7? or something. The locks are `dep` specific I believe.

Comment: Yes it is normal to put your dependencies in your project and keep them in the repo, remote or not. https://github.com/golang/dep does that too, as most other Go projects do too.

Comment: There are multiple different dependency management tools for Go, they all store the deps in the `vendor` folder because it's supported by Go, but they may have different ways of tracking the versions of the deps, `dep` uses .lock files; `Govendor` uses a vendor.json file, these are non-standard but the `vendor` folder is.

Comment: Make sure your project on the ci server / docker image is under go path directory as well. [This](https://github.com/vardius/go-api-boilerplate/blob/master/Dockerfile) is how I build my project under docker environment

Comment: @Vardius It is under $GOPATH. As you can see in my gitlab-ci.yml file, I'm creating $GOPATH/src/$REPO_NAME directory and symlinking all files to that directory. It is done same as in official golang template from gitlab.

Comment: Try to copy ur directories when running dep init in a directory that is linked it may not work

Comment: @Vardius Already tried. Same result as with symlinking. If finds half of dependencies, and when building is done, fails with same missing deps.

Comment: You may want to check some issues like [this one](https://github.com/golang/dep/issues/1146)

Comment: @Vardius Thank you for pointing to that problem again. Added cp -rf $CI_PROJECT_DIR/* $GOPATH/src/$REPO_NAME/ instead of symlink and it worked !!! You can make an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it might now work on a CI server might be the symlinks.
As said for example in this issue [Symlinked project root is not handled as I would expect](https://github.com/golang/dep/issues/1146).

You might want to hard copy your project files and give it a try. I think it should fix your issue.

This answer is summary of a talk leading to a solution between me and @user991 in a question comments.